# Find the measure of angle $MAN$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, angle

We construct two points $M,N$ such that perimeter of triangle $MCN$ is equal to half of the perimeter of the square.Find the measure of angle $MAN$.

The case $CM=CN$ leads to a simple equation so we can find the measure of $MAN$ using trigonometry.But in general case I don't no How to use equality of perimeter maybe we have to construct the same triangle in another place and use the sum of their perimeter.But I didn't get anything from this method.Any hints?

Comment: About which square do you say?

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear where point C is, and to what you are reffering square as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood about which square you say!

I think your problem is the following.

> Let $ABCD$ is a square with $AB=a$. $M\in BC$ and $N\in CD$ such that $CN+CM+MN=2a$. Find $\measuredangle MAN$.

Let $MC=x$ and $CN=y$.

Hence, $$x+y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2a,$$
$$AM=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+a^2}=\sqrt{2a^2-2ax+x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(x+y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2-\left(x+y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)x+x^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}.$$
By the same way we obtain:
$$AN=\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}.$$
Thus,
$$\measuredangle MAN=\arccos\frac{AM^2+AN^2-MN^2}{2AM\cdot AN}=$$
$$=\arccos\frac{4a^2-2a(x+y)+x^2+y^2-x^2-y^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}}=$$
$$=\arccos\frac{2a(2a-x-y)}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2+(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=$$

$$=\arccos\frac{a}{\sqrt{2a^2}}=\arccos\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=45^{\circ}.$$
Done!

Comment: Your second solution is exactly the particular case that  the OP has mentioned .

Comment: @Mick You are right! I deleted this part. Thank you!

Comment: It may not be necessary to have that deleted. A minor modification will indicate how the particular case is proved via a geometric approach.

Comment: @Mick Yes, I found it! Thank you! If $PM=PN$, $\measuredangle MPN=90^{\circ}$ and segments $PC$ and $MN$ intersects, then easy to see that $P$ is a circumcenter of $\Delta AMN$ (easy to see that $P\in AC$ and $PA=PM=PN$) and we are done! But it's your solution I think and I don't want to post it.

Comment: I just point out my finding and I didn't do anything toward the solution. Please! go ahead to have your proposed posted.

Comment: I can't just understand the line before the last.How did you simplify the denomiter?

Comment: @Taha Akbari $(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=x^2+y^2+xy+(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2=2a^2$. Just this line (about this line you are asking) is unnecessary. I'll delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

By the beautiful  Mick's hint we can get a nicer solution.

Let $P$ is a point inside our square $ABCD$ such that $PM=PN$, $\measuredangle MPN=90^{\circ}$

and segments $PC$ and $MN$ intersects.

Thus, $PMCN$ is cyclic and since $\measuredangle PCN=\measuredangle PMN=45^{\circ}$, we see that $P\in AC$.

Now, we'll use a rotation of $\Delta PCN$ around point $P$ on $90^{\circ}$.

Let $R^{90^{\circ}}_{P}\left(\Delta PCN\right)=\Delta{PKM}$.

Since $PMCN$ is cyclic, we obtain that $K$, $M$ and $C$ placed on common line $BC$.

In another hand, $\measuredangle KPC=90^{\circ}$.

Thus, $CP=KP=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}$ and $$AP=a\sqrt2-\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}=\frac{2a-x-y}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt2}=MP=NP,$$ 
which says that $P$ is a circumcenter of $\Delta AMN$ and
$$\measuredangle MAN=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle MPN=\frac{1}{2}\cdot90^{\circ}=45^{\circ}$$
and we are done!